# Change line in text file from other text file with command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-line

I need copy specific line of one text file, then is file replaced with selected other file and substitute same line with copied text line. I have command line:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set mca=%cd%
cd /d %SYSTEMDRIVE%\PMJ\PROGRAMS\
set programs=%cd%
:select
echo.
echo   Which file?
echo.
echo  (without.PRG)
echo.
set /p load=
if exist %programs%\%load%.PRG (goto start) else (goto err1)
:err1
echo Not found
goto select
:start
for /F "tokens=*" %%B in (%mca%\mlfb.txt) do (
    findstr /B /C:"  InterlockingName     = " %programs%\%%B > %mca%\actual.txt
    set /p "actual= < %mca%\actual.txt"
    copy /y %programs%\%load%.PRG %programs%\%%B
    fart -a %programs%\%%B "  InterlockingName     = " %actual%
)
```

Searched line begins `InterlockingName     =` then contains different characters.

File mlfb.txt contains

```
40AK11600.PRG
40AK11601.PRG
40AK11602.PRG
40AK11603.PRG
40AK11604.PRG
40AK11605.PRG
40AK11637.PRG
40AK11638.PRG
40AK11653.PRG
4OAK11609.PRG
5WK11706.PRG
A2C5330886804.PRG
A2C8171710004.PRG
```

Line

```
findstr /B /C:"  InterlockingName     = " %programs%\%%B > %mca%\actual.txt
```

creates file actual.txt, which contains string - for example

```
InterlockingName     = 40AK11600
```

Command

```
copy /y %programs%\%load%.PRG %programs%\%%B
```

replace one file with selected file, but I can not to substitute line of replaced file with line in file actual.txt

```
fart -a %programs%\%%B "  InterlockingName     = " %actual%
```

(if file actual.txt is not needed, it can be eliminated).

Comment: completely different question, but same [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) (delayed expansion)

Comment: Hi, how can I apply delayed expansion in the command line. I don't know nothing about it. Need I use more ()?

Comment: In a batchfile, you enable it with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` (When your batchfile ends, there is a implicite `endlocal`). On command prompt itself, you can't do it. However it is possible to start a _new_ command promt with delayed expansion enabled with  `cmd /v` (see `cmd /?`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working with command line modified (from :start point)

```
:start
for /F "tokens=*" %%B in (%mca%\mlfb.txt) do (
    findstr /B /C:"  InterlockingName     = " %programs%\%%B>%mca%\actual.txt & set /p actual=<%mca%\actual.txt
    copy /y %programs%\%load%.PRG %programs%\%%B
    findstr /B /C:"  InterlockingName     = " %programs%\%%B>%mca%\before.txt & set /p before=<%mca%\before.txt
    %fart% -a %programs%\%%B "!before!" "!actual!"
)
```